# Word search in C++

Tags: c++

I made a code which finds a word in a text file. The code works fine but the problem is that i need to search if the exact word is existed or not but it gives the same result even if it just part of another word.
Example im looking for the word 'Hello' but it says already existed cos the txt file has the word 'Hello_World' which is not the same but includes it.
How can i check for the exact word and ignore the others. Im thinking to do something with the length of the word and ignore anything longer but not sure.
The code is here:

```
cout << "\n Type a word: ";
    getline(cin, someword);

    file.open("myfile.txt");

    if (file.is_open()){
        while (!file.eof()){
            getline(file, line);
            if ((offset = line.find(someword, 0)) != string::npos){

                cout << "\n Word is already exist!! " << endl;
                file.close();
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
```

Comment: Try using regex instead of the `find` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to split words and search for the intended one:

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss(line);
while (getline(ss, tmp, ' ')){
    if (tmp == someword){
        //found
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! I made a mistake. I'll fixed this. Sorry.

Comment: This code assumes the line begins with the target word, does not account for punctuation, and fails when the word is a suffix of a longer word.

Comment: @Don Reba Sorry to be rude, but why do I have -1 for this answer?!

Comment: @bontoo Put it inside `while (!file.eof())` loop instead of `if ((offset = line.find(someword, 0)) != string::npos)` and it works for all lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
string line;
getline(file, line);

vector<string> words = TextToWords(line);
if (find(words.begin(), words.end(), someword) != words.end())
    cout << "\n Word already exists.\n";
```

The `TextToWords` implementation is up to you. Or use a regular expression library.

Comment: Cannot implement TextToWords